# Getting the list of command history using Clink

Tags: command-line, history, clink

I recently installed [Clink](https://mridgers.github.io/clink/) and I'm quite happy with the history being kept in between session and the ability to search history using <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl-S</kbd>.

However, I would very much like to have access to the full list of commands that Clink currently has, much like the `history` command on *nix system.

Despite what I consider thorough online search, I've not found any Clink hotkey or script to do so. If anyone has a working solution for that, I'd be very interested to hear about it.

Comment: Workaround: In clink_profile/settings set history_io=1 to sync all history to file; and then, cat clink_profile/.history

Comment: what is the actual path of clink_profile?

Comment: there is a "settings" file insidea a folder called "profile" inside the folder where clink is installed, usually `c:\Program Files (x86)\clink\profile\settings`

Comment: Hum. No. :-( I have `C:\Program Files (x86)\clink\0.4.8\<a bunch of files>` but no `profile` folder or `settings` file in there.

Comment: @joce type the command 'clink set' to find the settings and profile folder.

Comment: Clink https://github.com/mridgers/clink seems to be abandoned for years, have a look at maintained https://github.com/chrisant996/clink

Answer (score 20):

Workaround:

```
type "%LOCALAPPDATA%\clink\.history"
```

But by default clink writes history only on exit, to change it:

```
clink set history_io 1
```

or modify `history_io` value in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\clink\settings`

Comment: Perfect, this helped me to find the old commands i was looking for :)

Comment: Create a bat file with the first command called history. Sorted

Answer (score 4):

For this I use a history.bat file:

```
rem Batch file that provides bash history like list with numbered items
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set lno=1
for /F "delims=" %%h in ('type "%LOCALAPPDATA%\clink\.history"') do (
    echo !lno!: %%h
    set /A lno= !lno! + 1
)
```

Comment: `type %LOCALAPPDATA%\clink\.history | find /n /v ""`

Answer (score 2):

According to [this bug report](https://github.com/mridgers/clink/issues/138), it clink does not have a `history` command feature.

Comment: Indeed. Now, the question is: Is there a lua script floating somewhere that implement that feature?

Comment: That's probably for you to do ;).

Comment: Yeeeah... That's what I feared. And that's why I hoped someone would already have done it. :-/ Ho well.

Comment: Yay! It has been fixed! Time to update your answer!

Answer (score 2):

The ["renovated" version of Clink](https://chrisant996.github.io/clink/clink.html) has a `history` command, just like `bash`. Yay!

Comment: Oh! This is pretty cool!

Answer (score 0):

I have a portable version of `clink`
https://github.com/mridgers/clink/releases/download/0.4.9/clink_0.4.9.zip
, so the corresponding directory is `profile` under the `clink` directory.
There I see `.history` and `settings`.